# Lookup another sheet get whole row in sheet and no duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, vlookup

I have looked through the questions but somehow I just can't find what I am looking for.

What am I looking for?

I have a document with 2 sheets.
Let's say, sheet 1 is the backlog, sheet 2 is the sprint.
In the spreadsheet, I have a selection (with dropdown) where I can pick the sprint I want to see. When I click on a certain sprint I want all the rows in the backlog where this sprint is selected in my sprint sheet.

The format of the columns is exactly the same, so I just need to display the WHOLE row when the match is met.

I tried with Vlookup but as far as I found it is just for one cell.

If anyone could help I would be glad!

Comment: its not clear what you are asking for. provide a copy (sample) of your sheet or edit your question and add more information / examples. I recon to look up QUERY and FILTER

Comment: @user0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SLWwMz-8G9EKQCdDgFBYiKX8rgQUaaZct6xyBm_86_8/edit?usp=sharing made a copy that can be editted. I have the back-up in my drive. See sheet "Tijdelijke sprint backlog" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A3: `=QUERY('Product Backlog'!A2:G5,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C matches '"&B1&"'",0)`**

---

to avoid **#N/A**:

```
=IFERROR(
   QUERY('Product Backlog'!A2:G5,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C matches '"&B1&"'",0),
     "NO DATA")
```

Comment: Also thanks for the avoiding #N/A. Its an extra but will use this. Really thanks! :)